# Need help running Steam on Ubuntu

Tags: steam

When I try to launch Steam I get a pop up saying "glXChooseVisual failed"

From the terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
glXChooseVisual failedMain.cpp (309) : Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: glXChooseVisual failed
Assert( Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: glXChooseVisual failed ):Main.cpp:309

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1461972496)
[0526/021834:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0526/021834:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/maste/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160429221814)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1461968294)
[0526/021834:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
assert_20160526021834_6.dmp[23686]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20160526021834_6.dmp
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160429221814)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1461972496)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1461972496)
assert_20160526021834_6.dmp[23686]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20160526021834_6.dmp[23686]: response: CrashID=bp-e6a8248c-64d9-415e-b281-89dcb2160526
assert_20160526021834_6.dmp[23686]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160526021834_6.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-e6a8248c-64d9-415e-b281-89dcb2160526''
```

I appreciate all help, thanks!

Comment: Did you install steam from ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt-get install steam`) or did you download it from the site? In any case if you don't have any games installed try to remove it with  `sudo apt-get purge steam`, then delete the folders `~/.steam` and `~/.local/share/Steam` and reinstall it again after you download it from the site.

Comment: I just wanted to add that even with the package downloaded from the Steam website, it is not working for me either. I have the exact same failure message as output but everything else seems to be in place. Did you guys find any solution to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

try reinstalling the graphics driver

first answer on link below
[Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935)

Comment: Or restart the computer after having installed the graphics drivers...

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved by deleting this lib.

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
```

After this Steam is starting again. But I'am not sure if I broke things with this solution.

Comment: Did you get "glxchooseVisual failed" error before this fix?

Comment: yes, I got "glxchooseVisual failed" before